# Review beta: Content I've already reviewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I've already seen several questions about this, but none (I could find) cover the new beta review system.

When I review content on review beta, sometimes it comes back again. I only noticed it because of the new auto-comment feature. I got some answers I'd already reviewed/posted comments on less than ten minutes earlier to review.

Shouldn't there be something set up to not have the same reviewer review the same post when there are 46 thousand other low-quality posts? I love using review to help clean the site up, but it's hard to get the warm fuzzies when I keep getting the same stuff back.

**-EDIT-**

Okay, now there are only 36 thousand low-quality posts. But if we fixed this, maybe we'd be done already! I just went through a few hundred posts and it wasn't uncommon for me to see that one or two other reviewers had already commented (probably at least 20%).

Comment: I've only noticed that happen on 'Not Sure' so far - it doesn't keep track that I saw them already, and sometimes I see same post again.

Comment: @Dustin We're still looking into this; this is not by design. Are you able to recall which posts you saw multiple times and/or how you reviewed them?

Comment: @Emmett I haven't used the review system for a while as I'm on vacation. I believe that they were answers I marked as "not an answer" or something similar, and was able to confirm that I'd already viewed them by the presence of my autocomment. I am aware that there have been more builds that fixed some errors; this may have been an artifact of some other error. The most recent time I've had this happen was the 14th (when I edited this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found an issue with the way we were pushing audit tasks to people.  If this issue comes up again please let us know.