# How to handle posts I've already seen and flagged, in new review beta?

Tags: support, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review beta: Content I've already reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/review-beta-content-ive-already-reviewed)

In the new review beta (for example, [for low quality posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/)), what should I do about a post I've *already* seen and flagged for deletion? **Please note that I'm not talking about posts that *reappear* in the review, I'm talking about posts I've previously seen and flagged *during the normal course of using the site*.**

- Should I click "Not Sure" to skip over it? That seems wrong, since I *am* sure.
- Flagging it again seems wrong; another flag from the same user is not going to help moderators and 10k users decide what to do with the post.
- Saying it "Looks Good" seems wrong too. I've flagged it and I think it should be removed; I don't think it looks good.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/review-beta-content-ive-already-reviewed). I'm not asking about posts I've already reviewed, but rather about posts I've already seen and flagged just during the normal course of using the site. (After all, I don't *just* flag posts when using the review feature.) I've edited this question to clarify. Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should probably be reopened.