# Review Beta message when recommending to close a post you've already flagged does not move to next review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, flags, low-quality-posts

[This is related, but different.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142778/179372)

[This is not related, but looks similar.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144501/179372)

[This is very related, but was closed as a duplicate to the first link above (I believe in error).](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143470/179372)

When reviewing a low-quality post, I clicked the `Recommend Close` button and was presented with this message:

[image: Review Error]

It turns out I already made that decision prior to processing this review. However, once I click the box, nothing happens. The screen stays on the same review, and I am left with the same options. I could click `Not Sure` I suppose, but I don't know that any of the options are even close to appropriate.

**If the system knows that I've already reviewed a post, and I am proposing the same action as I have previously, then why not let me move on to the next review?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is somewhat of an edge case, it doesn't seem like too much trouble to just click "Skip" to continue reviewing.