# Review-beta likes to show the same things over and over and over again

Tags: discussion, bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Review beta: Content I've already reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/review-beta-content-ive-already-reviewed)

The new review-beta likes to show the same low-quality postings to the same person — me, but others have reported the same thing — repeatedly.  Is this a bug, or an accidental misfeature?

Comment: Are you clicking "not sure" or using an action on the post or just clicking "review" again? It should be taken out of your queue if you act on it or click Not Sure

Comment: @BenBrocka I am virtually certain that these were all actioned.  I seldom “pass”. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist?tab=activity). But I’m not going to click through 49 pages trying to find dupes, either.

Comment: @Ben "not sure" does nothing for me. And on more than one occasion it wasn't taken out of my queue even after I *edited, voted, and commented*. And then I'd naturally click on "Looks fine", and then an hour later I'd get presented with that same post yet again. It's getting boring.

Comment: This is not by design. If you see the same post in a queue more than once, it's probably a bug. (There are exceptions, e.g. if you say a post "Looks Good", then someone edits it, and it's still considered low-quality, then you may see it again.) Do you remember which posts you saw multiple times?

Comment: @Emmett: I just clicked on the "review" link, and [this is what I get](http://i.imgur.com/ogLbJ.png). I already reviewed that post 16 minutes ago. (Yes, via the Review page, not by simply editing it on the main site.)

Comment: @Emmett: haha, and now [again](http://i.imgur.com/0xLYH.png). This time it's something I reviewed an hour ago. Seriously, this happens *all the time*.

Comment: @RegDwight We [tracked down and fixed the issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144333/editing-a-post-shown-in-the-low-quality-posts-page-of-the-new-review-system-re/144372#144372) affecting the two posts in your screenshots. A javascript bug caused you to be redirected away review after saving edits, so you weren't considered to have "reviewed" it. It's fixed now: after clicking "Save Edits" the next review task should be loaded. We're still looking into what happened to tchrist, since he reported the issue before we introduced the javascript bug.

Comment: @tchrist Are you able to recall which posts you saw multiple times, and/or how you reviewed them?

Comment: @Emmett I viewed them through the review-beta low-quality posts, and saw that the same ones came up more than once, even though I had already actioned them. I don't right now recall which. If I do another batch, I'll keep my eye out for it.