# Editing a post shown in the "Low Quality Posts" page of the new review system redirects me to the question page after I am done

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, review

Today, I edited two posts that were shown in the "Low Quality Posts" page for the new review system. After I clicked on "Save Edits," I was asked if I wanted to leave the page, or stay on that page. Thinking it was a revival of a bug that was reported before, I clicked on "Leave page," and I was redirected to the page showing the question, with the edited post highlighted.

I noticed this only today. Before, I was not redirected to other pages, when editing low quality posts.

The edits I have done were saved, though. It is just a matter of being redirected to a different page when it is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Happened to me today as well. Javascript was loading slowly at that moment, and I assumed it was related to that (script not fully loaded caused a regular post instead of ajax?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently introduced a javascript bug (by [using `strict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it) while missing a `var`), which broke the submission flow on certain browsers. This caused the edit form to be submitted normally, as opposed to via ajax. It's fixed now; thanks for the report.