# Posts already reviewed by me show up again

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

When reviewing first posts using the "Review Tasks (beta)"-tool, I repeatedly get posts to review I already reviewed (clicked <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>) earlier the very same day. This happens when I access the review section several times and navigate to other sections of the site or completely away from SO in between.

Of course I can simply click <kbd>Not Sure</kbd>, but most often I read the first few sentences to recognize that I already reviewed that post.

Is that a desired behavior?

I tried to find similar posts here, but all were old or marked as fixed:

- [Posts I've already reviewed show up in the review section again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again)
- [Review beta: Content I've already reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/review-beta-content-ive-already-reviewed)

Comment: I found [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470255/windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-are-throwing-an-error-net-framework-3-5-is-n) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474670/php-login-script-using-specific-username-and-password-by-session-id) that you reviewed twice, but in each case, the first review appears to have been "Not Sure". ("Not Sure" should still prevent you from seeing it again, unless you specifically navigate to it.) Do you remember which posts you saw multiple times? That might help us track down the bug.

Comment: It was [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496639/php-never-testing-true-for-file-exists-while-evaluating-array-value/12496692#12496692) - But now you're making me unsure, but you can find that out: Did I simply answer that question and then it showed up? - Then there's already a [feature-request covering that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147086/activate-im-done-button-in-new-post-review-queue-if-i-have-already-acted-on-t)

Comment: Yea, for this particular case, you seem to have answered it first, and then came across it in the review queue a few hours later. I'll fix it to make sure that doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. If you have already provided an answer to a question, that question will not show up in your Firsts Posts queue.

Comment: It happened to me again yesterday and today about two or three times.