# Reviewing first posts and late answers, brings up already reviewed posts

Tags: bug, review

I don't know if I'm the only one experiencing this, but when I go to review posts from new members I keep getting the same ones over and over, again. [One in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/905753), I went to click on edit to fix the formatting of the question only to see it was already corrected. So, I skipped it, and it came up again when I was logged in from another device. Again I skipped it. Finally, the same exact post came up a third time, so I figured it was a glitch, and edited the edit to add a little clarification to what seemed to me was already clear. After I saved my edit, I saw that it had been edited twice before.

... And it's still in my queue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posts already reviewed by me show up again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147646/posts-already-reviewed-by-me-show-up-again)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, since Skip (the topic of this post) is supposed to work differently than I'm Done (the topic of that post).

Comment: Furthermore the bug in the duplicate had apparently been fixed - making this either a recurrence or something different