# Duplicate Low Quality Post in First Post & Late Answer - Double Flag?

Tags: discussion, review, late-answers

I've been occasionally seeing the same post show up in both First Post and Late Answers review queues, and I'm wondering what the expected behavior is if it appears again - should I flag it a 2nd time as a poor posting in the 2nd review category or just always press skip? It's tempting to flag again and have that count as an additional review but I don't want to annoy moderators this would come across as abusive double flagging.

I'm also wondering why review would show it to me a 2nd time if I've already indicated it has a problem in another review category, is that intentional for some reason or just maybe something that happens infrequently enough to not be worth coding a filter for?

Sorry If this has been asked before in a different way, I searched around for a bit and these were the closest questions I could find but didn't address showing up in multiple review categories:

[Reviewing first posts and late answers, brings up already reviewed posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153148/reviewing-first-posts-and-late-answers-brings-up-already-reviewed-posts)

[Posts already reviewed by me show up again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147646/posts-already-reviewed-by-me-show-up-again)

Comment: This example showed up in Late Answers, I flagged Not an Answer, and then was shown to me again in First Posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458850/how-to-read-serial-port-communication-into-buffer-and-parse-out-complete-message/13655345#13655345

Comment: WebChemist, I had the same problem just now, with the difference that the post then showed up even in the low quality list (where the button I am Done does not even exist - see animuson answer)- I don't know if you want to add this to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by-design. You actually don't even have to take any action the second time. If the same exact post shows up in another task and you'd already taken action on it in a previous task, the I'm Done button is enabled from the get-go. Just click it.

To answer about flagging, you can't. You can only have one pending flag per post, so if you attempt to flag it again, you'll just get a nice notice about not being able to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't actually tried to flag twice since I wasn't sure if it was abusive, didn't want to anger the SO Gods. Do you have any insight to share on why showing the already reviewed question again is by-design?

Comment: Is there really any reason why *not* to show already reviewed items? They explicitly enabled the I'm Done button so you wouldn't have to take *further* action on the post. You already reviewed and flagged it in one place, so why shouldn't your review also count in another place where it's relevant?

Comment: I didn't think it gave me a 2nd review point, guess I didn't notice that part- in that case I'll just shut up and take my extra review ;)

Comment: @animuson, I have just experienced the same problem. First flagged post in last answer quee, then saw it again in first post quee. As you said the button "I am done was already active". Problem is it then showed up in the poor quality list - now I only have "looks good", "edit" and "recomand deletion" as available actions - do you happen to know what is more appropiate in this situation?

Comment: - to clarify the above: normally I would just mark the answer for deletion (it was the classical "thank you"), but I am wondering if this could give problems to whoever will process the precedent flag.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do once one was flagged is to go to the other and refresh the page (note that I'm speaking as a user who does this normally on the responsive version (in my phone) and so refreshing the other tab is needed). Then you'll see the "No action needed" button getting inactive and the "I'm done" gets active. So you just need to click "I'm done".

This to me also shows that if what one looks for is increase review count, then it is a good procedure to open always both "First Posts" and "Late Answers" when there's that opportunity.