# Reviewing - late answers counted as first posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I've noticed that when I review first posts, late answers also sometimes show up automatically waiting to be review. I review them to and it's all fine.

The problem is that it seems that the counts always go towards first posts as it was the queue I selected for reviewing. My avatar icon shows up correctly in late answers but the count is increased for first posts.

Sorry if this question has already been asked - I tried to search for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: Chances are those `late answers` are actually new users.  As such, those fall into both categories.  But since you started out to review `First Posts`, you get credited for it.

Comment: That kind of makes sense but makes my first post going up much more quicker than late answers.

Comment: I have been wondering about this, given that First-Posts is defined as "Review first posts from new users" and Late-Answers is "Review late answers from new users" does everthing in Late-Answers also go into First-Posts. Or does a user keep their new status beyond the first post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157262/duplicate-low-quality-post-in-first-post-late-answer-double-flag) question (actually the answer therein) does indicate that it is *by design* that a post by a new user that is a *Late Answer* would appear in both *First Posts* and *Late Answers* queues.

Needless to say, you get credited for whichever category you opted to review.

Comment: Thanks for digging that up. But I can't agree that counting against the queue I selected is ok. It should be rather based on the type of review I'm doing.

Comment: @Szymon You may choose to report it as a bug.  The current implementation seems ok as well.  It's debatable.

Comment: True, it may go both ways. How do you actually report bugs?

Comment: Not sure!  Haven't reported one thus far.  I was about to suggest tagging it `bug`, but you seem to have done it already.