# Should the same user be able to review the same answer as First Post and also as Late Answer?

Tags: support, review, new-users, low-quality-posts, late-answers

Here are 2 reviews that were completed today (on Unix.SE):

- A [First Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/216400) review.
- A [Late Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/216403) review.

Things to notice about these reviews:

- both reviews are related to the [very same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402316/105997), and
- both reviews were reviewed by the [very same user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105997/pierre-vriens), aka me.

My question:
***Should the same user be able to review the same answer as [First Post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) and also as [Late Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers)?***

IMO this question is not a duplicate of "[Duplicate Low Quality Post in First Post & Late Answer - Double Flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157262/286501)", for these reasons:

- My scenario was created using 2 different browser tabs (similar to what [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) mentioned in a comment here). Though I bet using any of these variations, with the same user id, would lead to a similar result (none of them are mentioned in the above mentioned question):

  - 2 different browser windows.
  - 2 different browsers.
  - 2 different devices.
- The accepted answer to the above mentioned question talks about using the  <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button. However, in my 2 reviews mentioned above, it says that I used the <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>-button. And since those 2 buttons are mutually exclusive, I think it proofs that in my case I was not even able to use the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button. So that accepted answer seems to not apply to my question/scenario.

BTW, a similar scenario seems possible for these variations:

1. **First Posts** versus **Low Quality Posts**.
2. **Late Answers** versus **Low Quality Posts**.

Comment: FWIW, it's only possible if they open both review queues simultaneously (in different tabs).