# If I review a post in the First Posts queue, is it also removed from the Late Answers queue for everyone else?

Tags: support, review, new-users, late-answers

If a post appears in the First Posts queue and the Late Answers queue, and I review it in one of the queues, is it also removed from the other queue for everyone else?

I know that I cannot review the same post in both queues from experience on Music Fans SE. I also found this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Meta post that confirms this to be the case: [Posts already reviewed by me show up again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147646/313042).

However, does reviewing in one queue also remove it from the other queue for everyone else? I couldn't find any information about this anywhere. In particular, I checked the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) question [When is a review task marked "completed"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288/313042) but it doesn't explicitly address my question. This has also been asked in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164288/when-is-a-review-task-marked-completed?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment981411_190581) under the accepted answer there by [@MonicaCellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't:

> [image: Timeline showing a post that has gone through both Late Answer review (Reviewed x 1; completed May 22 at 6:42) and First Post review (No Action Needed x 1; completed May 22 at 0:17)]

But you can't review the same item in both queues. When you review it one of those queues, it disappears for you in the review count but you can still access the review using the actual review link as shown below (I reviewed both items):

> [image: Timeline showing a post that has gone through both Late Answer and First Post reviews, both completed as Reviewed x 1 20 hours ago]

Comment: I kinda think while invisible - adding image descriptions are in line with "how we do things" Kinda confused over the rollback war, but I think it ought to stop here.

Answer (score 9):

I've looked at some late answers/first posts and their timelines, and it seems the answer is 'no'.

[image: timeline of a post that has gone through both Late Answer review (completed May 2 at 22:23 and First Post review (completed May 1 at 10:31)]

As you can see in this image, the review for first post was done before the one for late answer, both were done by different people.

The opposite is also true, by the way: Reviewing a late answer also doesn't kick it from the first posts queue.